# How to reference array returned by Angular Service, in order to maintain state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a master object called "categories", which is returned by the `DataService`, and called by many different Controllers.

```
.service('DataService', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $q, $timeout) {

    var categories = {};

    // Return public API.
    return({
        setCategory: setCategory,
        getCategory: getCategory
    });

    function setCategory(activities, details) {
        var name = details.shortName,
            category = {};
        category.activities = activities;
        category.details = details;
        categories[name] = category;
    }

    function getCategory(name) {
        return categories[name];
    }
```

What is the correct way to access `categories` from the controllers in order to maintain state between all controllers?

For example, in Controller1 I want to grab the `categories` object property that matches `name`, and then add new values to an activity contained in it:

```
$scope.category = getCategory(name);
$scope.category.activities[2].input = true;
```

I then want to be able to access the value of `category.activities[2].input` everywhere that uses the `getCategories` service. But as far as I can tell this won't work because I've reassigned `categories[name]` to `$scope.category`, right?

Or, am I wrong, or taking entirely the wrong approach? What is the best way to call objects from the `categories` object, in a way that will allow me to preserve state across all controllers?

Comment: Just be sure to use DataService.setCategory each time a controller makes a change.  Then you can use $broadcast to send a message that the service has been changed, and use $on to trigger a refresh of the 'getCategory' method so you have the latest model in each of the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `$broadcast`. Use `$watch`

```
.value('categories',{})
.service("myService",function(categories,$rootScope) {
   $rootScope.$watch(function(){
      return categories;
   },function(val){
      console.log("Some controller, any controller, has updated categories!");
   },true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can call the DataService.setCategory each time a controller makes a change. Then you can use $broadcast to send a message that the service has been changed, and use $on to subscribe and trigger a refresh of the 'getCategory' method so you have the latest model in each of the controllers.

For example, in your service:

```
.service('DataService', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $http, $q, $timeout) {

    function setCategory(activities, details) {
        var name = details.shortName,
        category = {};
        category.activities = activities;
        category.details = details;
        categories[name] = category;

        $rootScope.$broadcast('categories:updated');
    }
```

And in the controllers:

```
.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'DataService', function($scope, $rootScope, DataService) {

    $scope.category = DataService.getService(name);

    $scope.category.activities[2].input = true;

    DataService.setCategory(category.activities, category.details);

}])

.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'DataService', function($scope, $rootScope, DataService) {

     $scope.category = DataService.getCategory(name);

     $scope.$on('categories:updated', function(){
         $scope.category = DataService.getCategory(name)             
     });

}]);
```